# Screenplay - How to switch window in a multi-method Task?

Tags: serenity-bdd

I am expanding from the [Slideshare tutorial](https://fr.slideshare.net/wakaleo/sustainable-test-automation-with-serenity-bdd-and-screenplay)
On slide 164, we replace a bunch of code lines with:

```
connie.attemptsTo(
            PlanAjourney.from("Waterloo").to("CanaryWharf").departingAt("09:00")
        );
```

PlanAJourney class with only first method from should look something like:

```
public class PlanAjourney
{
    public static PlanAjourney from(String departure)
    {
        return Task.where("{0} chooses #departure as a departure station",
            Enter.theValue(departure).into(JourneyPlanner.DEPARTURE_STATION)
        )
    }
}
```

Now imagine this is not a single page application but a multiwindow appl. Imagine Connie needs to switch to another window to see JourneyPlanner.DEPARTURE_STATION.

Now I would like to get the actor to be able to get the current window handle. This would be something like:

```
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Task;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.abilities.BrowseTheWeb;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.actions.Click;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.actions.Enter;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.actions.Switch;

    public class PlanAjourney
    {
    
        public static PlanAjourney from(String departure)
        {
            String currentWindowHandle = BrowseTheWeb.as(actor).getWindowHandle();
            return Task.where("{0} chooses #departure as a departure station",
                Click.on(HomePage.JOURNEY_PLANNER_LINK),
                Switch.to(getNewWindowHandle(actor, currentWindowHandle)),
                Enter.theValue(departure).into(JourneyPlanner.DEPARTURE_STATION)
            )
        }
    
        private static String getNewWindowHandle(Actor actor, String currentWindowHandle)
        {
            for (String windowHandle : BrowseTheWeb.as(actor).getDriver().getWindowHandles())
            {
                if (!windowHandle.equals(currentWindowHandle))
                {
                    return windowHandle;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But of course this doesn't compile because actor is not known.

How could I get the actor ? Or is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution.
First we have a method in a StepDefinition calling:

```
public class PlanAJourneyStepDefinitions {
    @When("^(.*) plans a journey from (.*) to (.*) departing at (.*)$")
    public void plan_a_journey(String name, String departure,
        String destination, String departureTime) throws Throwable {
        Actor theUser = theActorCalled(name);
        theUser.attemptsTo(
            PlanAjourney.from(departure, theUser)
                        .to(destination)
                        .departingAt(departureTime)
        );
    }  
}
```

We isolate the user to be able to pass him/her to the from method of PlanAjourney class.

Then it's easy to cope with the window switch:

```
public class PlanAjourney {

    public static PlanAjourney from(String departure, Actor theUser) {
        String currentHandle = BrowseTheWeb.as(theUser).getDriver().getWindowHandle();
        return Task.where("{0} chooses #departure as a departure station",
            Click.on(HomePage.JOURNEY_PLANNER_LINK),
            Switch.toWindow(getNewWindowHandle(theUser, currentHandle)),
            Enter.theValue(departure).into(JourneyPlanner.DEPARTURE_STATION)
        );
    }

    private static String getNewWindowHandle(Actor actor, String currentWindowHandle){
        for (String windowHandle : BrowseTheWeb.as(actor).getDriver().getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!windowHandle.equals(currentWindowHandle)) {
                return windowHandle;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But what I still don't get is how to make "from" method return an instance of PlanAJourney class. But that's a different question, so I will ask another one.